# Reverse words Codewars exercise syntax question

Tags: javascript

I attempted the Reverse words codewars exercise which I was eventually able to get right. But I have a solution that I thought should work, but isn't and I can't see why (although I'm sure it's right in front of my eyes). The below code returns string as normal, not reversed

```
function reverseWords(str) {

   let wordsArr = str.split(" ");
   wordsArr.map(e => e.split("").reverse().join(""));
   return wordsArr.join(" ");
}
```

however, when I chain all the methods instead of using map directly on to wordsArr it works fine.

```
function reverseWords(str) {

   let wordsArr = str.split(" ").map(e => e.split("").reverse().join(""));
   return wordsArr.join(" ");
}
```

I am wondering why this is? Thank you

Comment: `map()` returns a new array, it doesn't change items in place. So `wordsArr.map(...)` essentially gets discarded since you don't do anything with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Map doesn't mutate the original array and you are not using the reversed array when returning but the original wordsArr. You would have to do it like this:

```
const reverseWords = (str) => {
   const wordsArr = str.split(" ");
   const wordArr = wordsArr.map(e => e.split("").reverse().join(""));
   return wordArr.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

map() function returns a new array. Try storing the returned array.
Like

```
wordsArr = wordsArr.map(e => e.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to the other good answers there's no need to chain all on the same line which may make it easier to read. Simply `return` after all the operations are complete.

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  return str
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => word
      .split('')
      .reverse()
      .join('')
    ).join(' ');
}

console.log(reverseWords('Welcome to Stack overflow'));
```